# Fragmentos se solapan entre sí

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

### Fragments del un activity se solapan entre sí

> Creando un Bottom Nav Activity, a la hora de cambiar de fragmentos en el propio menú, estos se solapan entre sí. He probado de todo pero soy incapaz de hacer que estos se dejen de ver al cambiar de uno a otro.

[image: Como se aprecia, los fragmentos se ven uno tras del otro.]

```
class MenuPrincipalActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var BottomNavigationView : BottomNavigationView ?= null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_principal2)
    BottomNavigationView=this.findViewById(R.id.BottomNavigationView)
    BottomNavigationView!!.background = null
    BottomNavigationView!!.menu.getItem(2).isEnabled = false

    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

    val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
    val favFragment = DashboardFragment()
    val chatFragment = ForoFragment()
    val profileFragment = SettingsFragment()

    makeCurrentFragment(homeFragment)

    BottomNavigationView!!.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId){
            R.id.navHome -> makeCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
            R.id.navFav -> makeCurrentFragment(favFragment)
            R.id.navChat -> makeCurrentFragment(chatFragment)
            R.id.navSettings -> makeCurrentFragment(profileFragment)
        }
        true
    }
}

private fun makeCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) =
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
        commit()
    }
```

}

Comment: Es probable que le hayas puesto un background transparente a tus fragments

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear una función que configure el BottomNav y llamarla en el onCreate de tu Fragment, la función debería ser algo así

```
private lateinit var mBinding: ActivityMainBinding

private lateinit var mActiveFragment: Fragment
private lateinit var mFragmentManager: FragmentManager

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(mBinding.root)

    
    setupBottomNav()
}

    private fun setupBottomNav(){
    mFragmentManager = supportFragmentManager

    val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
    val chatFragment = ForoFragment()

    mActiveFragment = homeFragment

    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()  
        .add(R.id.hostFragment, chatFragment, ForoFragment::class.java.name)
        .hide(chatFragment).commit()
    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.hostFragment, homeFragment, HomeFragment::class.java.name).commit()

    mBinding.navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId){
            R.id.navHome -> {
                mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(mActiveFragment).show(homeFragment).commit()
                mActiveFragment = homeFragment
                true
            }
            R.id.navChat -> {
                mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(mActiveFragment).show(chatFragment).commit()
                mActiveFragment = chatFragment
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo estoy usando Binding para encontrar los componentes pero puedes reemplazarlo por el finViewById si no quieres agregar la funcionalidad.

La función en la primera parte llama a todos los fragments, los esconde y deja al home fragment en la pantalla, luego con setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener seleccionas un elemento, lo pones en la vista y escondes el anterior, en este caso no necesitas tu función makeCurrentFragment().